# Redefine function pointer

Tags: c++, function-pointers

converter.h is inside a library that is used in many different projects. In one, containing mod_converter.h, I'd like to modify fooToString(). But compiling the latter project gives me an error. I'm using Visual Studio 2008.

converter.h

```
std::string impl_fooToString(Foo f);
static std::string (*fooToString)(Foo f) = &impl_fooToString; // line 29
```

mod_converter.h

```
std::string mod_fooToString(Foo f);
fooToString = &mod_fooToString; // line 10
```

Compiler error (translated):

```
mod_converter.h(10) : error C4430: Missing type specifier: int assumed
mod_converter.h(10) : error C2373: 'fooToString': redefinition; different type modifier
        converter.h(29) : see declaration of fooToString
mod_converter.h(10) : error C2440: Cannot convert from 'std::string (__cdecl *)(Foo)' to int
    There is no context in which this conversion is possible.
```

Comment: Is line 10 inside a function body?  If not, then that's not valid code.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth No it's not. I'll search a function to properly put that command into.

Answer (score 0):

@OliCharlesworth figured it out. This is how it has to look like

mod_converter.h:

```
std::string mod_fooToString(Foo f);

void setPointers() { // this was missing...
    fooToString = &mod_fooToString;
}
```